# Replace Everything between Name and Title In Mule

Tags: regex, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am getting a Long URL as String which contains query parameters (Name, Title, Location). I like to Replace Name and Title with Position.

Values in the Name and Title are unique for every request.

Incoming Request:

```
{
    "url":"https://test.com/IncomingRequest?Name=MuleSoft&Title=Developer&Location=Headquaters"
}
```

Excepted Output:

```
{
    "url" : "https://test.com/IncomingRequest?Position=North&Location=Headquaters"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regex:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%var input = {"url" : "https://test.com/IncomingRequest?Name= MuleSoft&Title=Developer&Location=Headquaters"}
---
url: input.url replace /Name.+?(?=&Location)/ with "Position=North"
```

Output:

```
{
  "url": "https://test.com/IncomingRequest?Position=North&Location=Headquaters"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @utechtzs for your answer. Please see my comments below. Your inputs are really appreciated. Thanks Much!

Comment: Yes. You can use an or in the regex. I’ll try to update the answer in the next 24. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @utechtzs for the updated answer. I am getting the expected output now.

Thanks much.